# How to set flutter POST method using DIO?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

This is my code below, i'm stuck please help. How to set flutter POST method using DIO?

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
        'id': id,
         "name": name,
         "telNumber": telNumber,
         "email": email,
         "age": age
      };
   }

String postToJson(Post data){
      final dyn = data.toJson();
      return json.encode(dyn);
}

Future<http.Response> createPost(Post post) async {
          final response = await http.post(
               "$baseUrl/users",
              headers: {
                  "content-type": "application"
                    },
              body: postToJson(post));
              return response;
            }
```

This method works in http

Answer (score 3):

```
 BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
     baseUrl: $baseUrl,
     connectTimeout: 10000,
     receiveTimeout: 10000,);
final dioClient = Dio(options);
try{
   final response = await dioClient.post("/users", data: FormData.fromMap(
      postToJson(post))
    ),);
   return response;
} catch (e) {
  throw (e);
}
```

Put this code inside the function

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new function and call this from anywhere:

```
Future<Null> SendPost() async {

    Response response;
    BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: "https://your.url",
      connectTimeout: 6000,
      receiveTimeout: 3000,
    );
    Dio dio = new Dio(options);

    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      "post_data1": value,
      "post_data2": value,
    });

    try {
      response=await  dio.post("/page.php", data: formData);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }
```