# Flutter api fetching

Tags: flutter

I am working on a flutter project and I send the data to the internet through API and the API create the user id, Then next page I have to fetch the id and then fill some data and post the data to the respect id, So how I do this please help me for this I am using the dio package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set flutter POST method using DIO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155870/how-to-set-flutter-post-method-using-dio)

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to create an instance of Dio. It is useful to define baseUrl upfront. It will allow you to only specify your endpoint path instead of repeating the full url for each request.

```
var options = BaseOptions(baseUrl: 'https://[hostname]/api');

Dio dio = Dio(options);
```

To send a GET request you just need to call the get method of the dio instance, queryParameters are optional.

```
response = await dio.get([endpoint path], queryParameters: { ... });
```

To send a POST request you need to call post method of the dio instance, data must be passed a Map.

```
response = await dio.post([endpoint path], data: { ... });
```

Finally, response data is accessible through `response.data`.